# Practicality of using POST to create a complex query resource then GETing the results:

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I am designing .Net WebApi service and an AngularJS client. One particular feature of the client is a fairly complex search engine for a particular type of resource. The search query is ideally represented in an object graph. I'm wrestling with the fact that I am semantically supposed to be sending this request to the service as a GET request with the search query encoded into the url. The problem is that it is way too much data for a query string, and everything I'm reading has firmly led me to believe I should not use the message body in a GET request in a situation like this.

I have seen a solution suggested a couple times which seems a bit clumsy but at least sematically correct:

1. Create an api in the service for POSTing search query resources.
2. Create an api in the service for GETing search query results.

If I do implement this api in the service, there still is no easy way to bookmark or link to the search results in the client (because if the query was reasonably representable in a url, this whole question wouldn't need to be asked).

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Your description is a bit vague, but one thing to consider is to provide a bunch of specialized queries in addition to or instead of the complex search.

Comment: I do not believe breaking this up into smaller queries is feasible in this case, but I will entertain it as a thought exercise. But let's assume for the time being that is not an option... My question still stands.

Comment: The solution you suggested is about specialized queries ^^

Answer (score 0):

The solution you've found is actually a nice and simple way of handling this sort of thing:

- you create your query and POST it to the server;
- a `query` resource is created for it and stored on the server;
- you return an URL for that created `query` (you don't execute it yet). I think this is better done with a [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) so the URL can be bookmarked;
- client does a GET to the URL and at this point the `query` is executed and results are returned;
- every time you GET that URL, the same `query` is executed.

Now, as a refinement you could allow the user to give the `query` a friendly name when she creates it (e.g. `queryForXYZBlaWhatever`) and return this as part of the URL `http://server/api/query/queryForXYZBlaWhatever`. This can be bookmarked, shared, emailed whatever and it will always point to the same `query`.

Comment: Yeah, after mulling this over, I do think this is the best solution. The only thing I'm concerned about is that in order for the query GET urls to be valid forever, I have to store these queries forever, which could cause my database to blow up in size. Do you think that's a realistic problem to be worried about?

Comment: @Kelsie: Depending on how big the queries are and how often a new one is created this can indeed be a valid concern. You don't mention the type of business for which this service is for, but do those URLs need to be valid forever? Are their results still relevant after a long time? If not, you could have an expiration policy on them, like, if unused for more than a month, delete them. If they need to be kept forever then you need to estimate/compute database growth on some time horizon and see if that can indeed turn into an issue.